# Example where Alexandroff compactification $X^*$ is connected but the initial space $X$ is not

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space that admits a one-point compatification $(X^{*},\tau)$ (Alexandroff compatification). I know that if the space $X$ is connected, then $X^*$ is connected as well. However, the converse is not neccesarly true, that is, the Alexandroff compatification can connect a disconnected space. Can anyone provide examples where this happens? That is, a disconnected space such that its Alexandroff compatification is connected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does it work? I thought of something like that but it seemed like if I was missing something. Thank you!

Comment: I shot it from the hip. I'm not sure if it actually works. But it's worth checking, I mean if $U\subseteq [0,1)\cup(1,2]$ is open with a complement which is compact, then I think it has to be the case that from each interval, $U$ contains an interval with $1$ as an endpoint.

Comment: @A.Jiménez you can look at the proof in my answer to get some intuition on what is going in such examples

Comment: Take any compact connected Hausdorff space $X$ such that for some point $p$ (a so-called cut-point) $Y=X\setminus \{p\}$ is not connected. Then the one-point compactification of $Y$ is $X$ (connected) while $Y$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb R^*= S^1$ and similarily $(\mathbb R-0)=S^1\vee S^1$.

Edit: Actually thinking about it, everything (if not already compact) will get connected. By that I mean:

Proposition: Let $X=X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_n$ with its $n$ components $X_i$ all non-compact. Then $X^*$ is connected.

Proof: We have canonical inclusions $\iota_i:X_i \to X^*$, and the closure of $X_i$ in $X^*$ always contains $*$. Let $A\cup B =X^*$ be a disjoint clopen cover. Then if $*\in A$ it follows that $X_i\cap A\neq \emptyset$ for all $X_i$. Hence by pulling the situation back to $X$, we see that $X\subset A$ and therefore $A=X^*$.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that it works in this generality.

Comment: Nice! So basically your proof states that spaces like $[0,1)\cup (1,2]$ work as counterexamples of disconnected spaces with a connected one-point compatification?

Comment: It's kind of a surprising result

Comment: Yes precisely. The picture behind this is that the 1-pt-compactifcation of a space $X$ glues *all* "open" ends of $X$ together onto a single point.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. It doesn't only answer my question, but provides an explicit construction showing how to construct it. Thank you!